When using OpenOCD for Flash debugging of STM32, the program dies in HardFault_Handler
My development environment is

Windows10
Clion2023.3.6
arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.Rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi
mingw64(Clion bundle)
openocd-v0.12.0-i686-w64-mingw32
Jlink(V12)
STM32F103C8T6

I configured everything about Clion, the code compiled properly, and most importantly, it could debug SRAM (one of STM32's three boot modes, BOOT0 is 1). However, if I was debugging with the main flash (BOOT0 is 0), the program would get an exception error and die.
In which line of the program did the hardware error occur? I guess it doesn't matter, it shouldn't be a problem with the code, but what happens when the program encounters some kind of bug (that I want to find). Although it can stably reproduce a certain code.
Below I provide my source code, and some configuration:
https://github.com/njki/STM32F1x_Template
I tried using Keil and it worked very well. I haven't tried Stlink yet.
I would like to know how to solve the above problem so that my program can Debug and burn properly.
I'd appreciate it if you could give me some advice, including some ideas.
Info : J-Link V12 compiled Oct  9 2024 10:52:31
Info : Hardware version: 12.00
Info : VTarget = 3.212 V
Info : clock speed 1000 kHz
Info : SWD DPIDR 0x2ba01477
Info : [stm32f1x.cpu] Cortex-M3 r2p1 processor detected
Info : [stm32f1x.cpu] target has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Info : starting gdb server for stm32f1x.cpu on 3333
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
[stm32f1x.cpu] halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x08000198 msp: 0x20010000
** Programming Started **
Info : device id = 0x20036410
Info : flash size = 128 KiB
Warn : Adding extra erase range, 0x080003d0 .. 0x080003ff
** Programming Finished **
(((READY)))
Info : tcl server disabled
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
Info : acceptDebugger connected to tcp:localhost:3333
ing 'gdb' connection on tcp/3333
[stm32f1x.cpu] halted due to debug-request, current mode: Handler HardFault
xPSR: 0x61000003 pc: 0x08000366 msp: 0x2000ffd4
Warn : Prefer GDB command "target extended-remote :3333" instead of "target remo
te :3333"
Signal: SIGINT (Interrupt)
Info : SWD DPIDR 0x2ba01477
Error: Failed to read memory at 0x2000fff8
Info : SWD DPIDR 0x2ba01477
Error: Failed to read memory at 0x2000ffc4

Where the program terminates unexpectedly
/**
  * @brief  This function handles Hard Fault exception.
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
void HardFault_Handler(void)
{
  /* Go to infinite loop when Hard Fault exception occurs */
  while (1)
  {
  }
}

The main function is empty because the program cannot access the main function at all and fails to configure the clock
Reset_Handler:

  movs  r1, #0
  b LoopCopyDataInit

CopyDataInit:
    ldr r3, =_sidata
    ldr r3, [r3, r1]
    str r3, [r0, r1]
    adds    r1, r1, #4

LoopCopyDataInit:
    ldr r0, =_sdata
    ldr r3, =_edata
    adds    r2, r0, r1
    cmp r2, r3
    bcc CopyDataInit
    ldr r2, =_sbss
    b   LoopFillZerobss
FillZerobss:
    movs    r3, #0
    str r3, [r2], #4

LoopFillZerobss:
    ldr r3, = _ebss
    cmp r2, r3
    bcc FillZerobss

        bl  SystemInit      //**This is usually where a hardware error occurs**
        bl __libc_init_array
    bl  main
    bx  lr
.size   Reset_Handler, .-Reset_Handler


int main(void) {
    while(1){

    }
}


I would suggest to stop playing with DIY build systems before you learn how to debug HardFaults.
Install STM32CubeIDE where everything is configured for you.
Protential problems:

wrong pin configuration
wrong linker script
wrong openOCD configuration.
incorrect startup code

To see what really happened write
#include <stdint.h>

__attribute__((naked))
void HardFault_Handler(void) 
{
    __asm volatile (
        "TST LR, #4            \n"
        "ITE EQ                \n"
        "MRSEQ R0, MSP         \n"
        "MRSNE R0, PSP         \n"
        "B HardFault_Handler_C \n"
    );
}

void HardFault_Handler_C(uint32_t *pulFaultStackAddress) {
    // Registers saved on the stack
    volatile uint32_t r0  = pulFaultStackAddress[0];
    volatile uint32_t r1  = pulFaultStackAddress[1];
    volatile uint32_t r2  = pulFaultStackAddress[2];
    volatile uint32_t r3  = pulFaultStackAddress[3];
    volatile uint32_t r12 = pulFaultStackAddress[4];
    volatile uint32_t lr  = pulFaultStackAddress[5]; // Link register
    volatile uint32_t pc  = pulFaultStackAddress[6]; // Program counter
    volatile uint32_t psr = pulFaultStackAddress[7]; // Program status register

    // Optional: Retrieve fault status registers
    volatile uint32_t CFSR = (*((volatile uint32_t *)(0xE000ED28))); // Configurable Fault Status Register
    volatile uint32_t HFSR = (*((volatile uint32_t *)(0xE000ED2C))); // HardFault Status Register
    volatile uint32_t DFSR = (*((volatile uint32_t *)(0xE000ED30))); // Debug Fault Status Register
    volatile uint32_t AFSR = (*((volatile uint32_t *)(0xE000ED3C))); // Auxiliary Fault Status Register
    volatile uint32_t MMAR = (*((volatile uint32_t *)(0xE000ED34))); // MemManage Fault Address Register
    volatile uint32_t BFAR = (*((volatile uint32_t *)(0xE000ED38))); // BusFault Address Register

    // Implement your debugging or logging here
    // For example, you can print the values or store them in a buffer
    // Halt the system or reset
    while (1);
}

And analyze in the debugger (as you have one) with Programming Manual opened in another window context of the registers.
